# changing the displayed labels on a tableau liner graph

Tags: graph, tableau-api

In my tableau visualization I need to show the change in a metric over every minute for a day.

I have a "**minutes**" table in my db. Each row has columns: "minute_id", type int 
"minute", type string: carries the value of the time eg: "05:33, 12.30, etc"
"min_date_time", type datetime: carries the value of the time datetime equivalent of the above string value eg: "2013-11-01 2:30:00 AM, 2013-11-01 2:31:00 AM, etc"

A second table called "**demos**" has all the metrics that are shown for that specific minute.It has relevant columns as follows:
"minute_id", type int: foreign key for the minutes table
"ind2plus", type float: value to be displayed on the y axis for each "minute_id"

This is what I have so far:

[image]

```
The problem Im trying to solve is:
On the X axis currently the displayed unit is "minute_id". 
I would like to keep minute_id as the values on the X axis,
 but I would like to change the values "displayed" as labels on the X axis from 
the int value in the "minute_id" column to the string value in the "minute" for every "minute_id".
```

How do I do that? Please advise.

UPDATED GRAPH:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a true datetime field in your data, you get more flexibility by using that field for most situations.

So I suggest putting your min_date_time field on the columns shelf to replace minute_id.

Tableau allows you to use dates and time fields in many different ways for different effects -- so many options that it can be confusing. You have to choose whether to treat the field as a dimension or measure, whether to treat it as discrete or continuous, and what level of granularity to use (hour, minute, month, exact date ...) It will take experimentation and experience to get comfortable with implications of the different choices.

For your graph, I would start by choosing a continuous dimension at the minute level. You can adjust the settings by clicking the little triangle on the right of the pill on the columns shelf. The truncated date settings are the **second** batch of date menu options and result in a green pill. Once set, you can drill up/down granularity with the + on the left of the pill.

Finally, once you are happy with your chart, you can change the formatting instructions to affect how dates are displayed on the axis. Right click on a number on the axis, choose format, and then in the format pane, under scale you should see a pull down labelled Dates. You can choose one of the existing date formats or enter a custom one. The format strings are pretty much what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alex. I changed my x axis from the minute_id to min_date_time field. Then made it continuous and drilled down to minute. My graph changed to the one above: ( I uploaded a second image)

Comment: Did you by any chance turn off aggregation under the analysis menu? That could be part of it. If you can post your workbook somewhere with sample data, say at Tableau public, then it would be easier to diagnose.

Comment: You also should make sure you selected the minute level of granularity from the SECOND batch of choices in the menu - the set with whole dates in the examples instead of just extracted parts of dates